# Invoking additional generator in Rails default scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-generation

In our project, we are currently using Policy classes to allow authorization for users. This is present for every model, so I want to add the `policy_generator` and `policy_spec_generator` to the existing `rails g scaffold` command so it will create the relevant models, controllers, views and my new policy files (both the Policy and spec) all in a single command.

How do I go about doing this? My initial thought would be to look into Railties and edit the files using the `lib` folder, but I can't seem to figure out what or where to add the code. Thanks!

#### UPDATE

So I've been trial and testing for a good part of the day and came up with a solution. What I did was to copy the code for rails' `scaffold_generator.rb` into my `lib` **BUT** it must be with the correct namespacing (in my case, `lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller/scaffold_controller_generator.rb`). I'm sure it'd be the same path in any rails project but give it a few go to make sure.

Also, I notice that the patterns for modifying generator files have been like so `lib/rails/generators/rails/<generator_folder>/<generator_file>_generator.rb` and it's template in this path `lib/templates/rails/<generator_folder>/<generator_file>.rb`. It's pretty confusing at first since it doesn't match the `lib` path in Railties or other gems.

As for the actual method itself, here's a copy of the `scaffold_controller_generator.rb`. I've added a comment where I added my `create_policy_file` method. The rest are unchanged.

```
module Rails
  module Generators
    class ScaffoldControllerGenerator < NamedBase # :nodoc:
      include ResourceHelpers

      check_class_collision suffix: "Controller"

      class_option :helper, type: :boolean
      class_option :orm, banner: "NAME", type: :string, required: true,
                         desc: "ORM to generate the controller for"
      class_option :api, type: :boolean,
                         desc: "Generates API controller"

      class_option :skip_routes, type: :boolean, desc: "Don't add routes to config/routes.rb."

      argument :attributes, type: :array, default: [], banner: "field:type field:type"

      def create_controller_files
        template_file = options.api? ? "api_controller.rb" : "controller.rb"
        template template_file, File.join("app/controllers", controller_class_path, "#{controller_file_name}_controller.rb")
      end
      
      # My new method to generate policy files
      def create_policy_files
        template "policy.rb", File.join("app/policies", controller_class_path, "#{singular_name}_policy.rb")
      end

      hook_for :template_engine, as: :scaffold do |template_engine|
        invoke template_engine unless options.api?
      end

      hook_for :resource_route, required: true do |route|
        invoke route unless options.skip_routes?
      end

      hook_for :test_framework, as: :scaffold

      # Invoke the helper using the controller name (pluralized)
      hook_for :helper, as: :scaffold do |invoked|
        invoke invoked, [ controller_name ]
      end

      private
        def permitted_params
          attachments, others = attributes_names.partition { |name| attachments?(name) }
          params = others.map { |name| ":#{name}" }
          params += attachments.map { |name| "#{name}: []" }
          params.join(", ")
        end

        def attachments?(name)
          attribute = attributes.find { |attr| attr.name == name }
          attribute&.attachments?
        end
    end
  end
end
```

For generatig the spec files, you can just add it inside the file above in the same method even but it's not that pretty. What I did then is to add it inside rspec's `scaffold_generator.rb`.

Here's the `scaffold_generator.rb`. Namespacing it is important! Mine's at `lib/rails/generatots/rspec/scaffold/scaffold_generator.rb`. To find out where I get this path, look into RSpec's `lib` folder in its repo and follow the same pattern to add it to your project.

```
require 'generators/rspec'
require 'rails/generators/resource_helpers'

module Rspec
  module Generators
    # @private
    class ScaffoldGenerator < Base
      include ::Rails::Generators::ResourceHelpers
      source_paths << File.expand_path('../helper/templates', __dir__)
      argument :attributes, type: :array, default: [], banner: "field:type field:type"

      class_option :orm, desc: "ORM used to generate the controller"
      class_option :template_engine, desc: "Template engine to generate view files"
      class_option :singleton, type: :boolean, desc: "Supply to create a singleton controller"
      class_option :api, type: :boolean, desc: "Skip specs unnecessary for API-only apps"

      class_option :controller_specs, type: :boolean, default: false, desc: "Generate controller specs"
      class_option :request_specs,    type: :boolean, default: true,  desc: "Generate request specs"
      class_option :view_specs,       type: :boolean, default: true,  desc: "Generate view specs"
      class_option :helper_specs,     type: :boolean, default: true,  desc: "Generate helper specs"
      class_option :routing_specs,    type: :boolean, default: true,  desc: "Generate routing specs"
      class_option :policy_specs,     type: :boolean, default: true,  desc: "Generate policy specs"

      def initialize(*args, &blk)
        @generator_args = args.first
        super(*args, &blk)
      end

      def generate_controller_spec
        return unless options[:controller_specs]

        if options[:api]
          template 'api_controller_spec.rb', template_file(folder: 'controllers', suffix: '_controller')
        else
          template 'controller_spec.rb', template_file(folder: 'controllers', suffix: '_controller')
        end
      end

      def generate_request_spec
        return unless options[:request_specs]

        if options[:api]
          template 'api_request_spec.rb', template_file(folder: 'requests')
        else
          template 'request_spec.rb', template_file(folder: 'requests')
        end
      end

      def generate_view_specs
        return if options[:api]
        return unless options[:view_specs] && options[:template_engine]

        copy_view :edit
        copy_view :index unless options[:singleton]
        copy_view :new
        copy_view :show
      end

      def generate_routing_spec
        return unless options[:routing_specs]

        template_file = File.join(
          'spec/routing',
          controller_class_path,
          "#{controller_file_name}_routing_spec.rb"
        )
        template 'routing_spec.rb', template_file
      end

      # My new method to generate policy spec files
      def generate_policy_spec
        return unless options[:policy_specs]

        template_file = File.join(
          'spec/policies',
          controller_class_path,
          "#{singular_name}_policy_spec.rb"
        )
        template 'policy_spec.rb', template_file
      end

    protected

      attr_reader :generator_args

      def copy_view(view)
        template "#{view}_spec.rb",
                 File.join("spec/views", controller_file_path, "#{view}.html.#{options[:template_engine]}_spec.rb")
      end

      # support for namespaced-resources
      def ns_file_name
        return file_name if ns_parts.empty?

        "#{ns_prefix.map(&:underscore).join('/')}_#{ns_suffix.singularize.underscore}"
      end

      # support for namespaced-resources
      def ns_table_name
        return table_name if ns_parts.empty?

        "#{ns_prefix.map(&:underscore).join('/')}/#{ns_suffix.tableize}"
      end

      def ns_parts
        @ns_parts ||= begin
                        parts = generator_args[0].split(/\/|::/)
                        parts.size > 1 ? parts : []
                      end
      end

      def ns_prefix
        @ns_prefix ||= ns_parts[0..-2]
      end

      def ns_suffix
        @ns_suffix ||= ns_parts[-1]
      end

      def value_for(attribute)
        raw_value_for(attribute).inspect
      end

      def raw_value_for(attribute)
        case attribute.type
        when :string
          attribute.name.titleize
        when :integer, :float
          @attribute_id_map ||= {}
          @attribute_id_map[attribute] ||= @attribute_id_map.keys.size.next + attribute.default
        else
          attribute.default
        end
      end

      def template_file(folder:, suffix: '')
        File.join('spec', folder, controller_class_path, "#{controller_file_name}#{suffix}_spec.rb")
      end

      def banner
        self.class.banner
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this helps others who's battling code generation too!

Comment: I believe have an answer to this question, but it is already closed. If you able to add to this question more specific details based on the answer below then update your question and follow these recommendations to reopen it https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253278/9548002
 or create a new one

Comment: Take a look at my solution without copying core files. Will it work for you? https://gist.github.com/annikoff/331f785aa7a207a7945b1eca6eff526b

Comment: @Yakov your solutions does looks good! I don't see why it won't. I'll see if I can go back to this task and refactor it. Also, do you happen to know of any up-to-date and extensive tutorials on code generations? I'm not picking up a lot from the docs alone.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know such tutorials. I've read a couple of articles and Rails docs. The approach with hooks, I picked-up in `active_model_serializers` source code https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/lib/generators/rails/resource_override.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look into the official guide here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#creating-your-first-generator.

Short summary, create a file in `lib/generators/initializer_generator.rb` with this content:

```
class InitializerGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
  def create_initializer_file
    create_file "config/initializers/initializer.rb", "# Add initialization content here"
  end
end
```

and execute it with `rails generate initializer`.

There is even a generator which can do this for you https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#creating-generators-with-generators.