# Rails hooking a custom generator into scaffold generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a new Rails 6.1.3 [project](https://github.com/diachini/generator_hook_investigation), I'm attempting to have `bin/rails generate scaffold Thing name:string` invoke the typical Rails scaffolding (including `active_record` and `scaffold_controller`) as well as invoking my own custom generator to create an additional `ThingForm` that I want to be a part of my scaffolding.

I created a custom generator for `form` that works just fine by itself. `bin/rails generate form Thing name:string` is properly setting up an `app/forms/thing_form.rb`.

But in attempting to get this generator hooked into the default scaffolding generator, I'm running into different problems with different approaches I've tried.

1. Inspired by [`active_model_serializers`](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/lib/generators/rails/resource_override.rb#L9), when I set up a `hook_for :form` as part of `Rails::Generators::ResourceGenerator` it ends up no longer invoking `active_record`. Here's the commit from my example repo: https://github.com/diachini/generator_hook_investigation/commit/8989b8f96b05ac1157d1d3a247bee9f0f2befe5d

   - To confirm I wasn't crazy, I have [another branch](https://github.com/diachini/generator_hook_investigation/tree/active_model_serializers_keeps_active_record) that just confirmed generating a scaffold with `active_model_serializers` installed properly keeps the `active_record` invocation happening.
2. Taking a page out of [this Gist explaining custom generators](https://gist.github.com/annikoff/331f785aa7a207a7945b1eca6eff526b#a-hook-to-invoke-the-custom-generator-with-scaffolding-or-with-controllers-generators) - I similarly attempted a `hook_for`on the `ScaffoldGenerator` and the `ControllerGenerator`

   - Just like my `active_model_serializers` attempt, this no longer invoked `active_record`.
   - It also began ignoring config for turning off `assets` and `scaffold_stylesheet`.
   - On a separate branch in my example repo: https://github.com/diachini/generator_hook_investigation/commit/86bc7b53ac34ea29d5e32d07486c73d962f86247
3. I saw a similar [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62381447/invoking-additional-generator-in-rails-default-scaffold) with an update regarding copying the *whole* `ScaffoldGenerator`, but was hoping to avoid that approach if there's something simple that I'm missing with the `hook_for` approach that `active_model_serializers` took.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: This seems to work but it not invoking the model generator now - https://gist.github.com/annikoff/331f785aa7a207a7945b1eca6eff526b#application-config-to-hook-up-custom-generators

Comment: Ohh I see you already referred to the same gist